# How to transform a list (strsplit output) into logical data frame (according to column names) in R

Tags: r, list, boolean-logic, strsplit

this is my first post and obviously, I do not have programming experience.

Problem:

I have a list of 200 character vectors, ranging from 0 to 7 elements each: (this list is the output of the strsplit function).

```
>input

> [[1]]
>> [1] "foo" "bar" "norf"
> [[2]]
>> [1] "norf"
> [[3]]
>> NA
.....
> [[200]]
>> [1] "hello" "norf"
```

I also have a character string of all potential character strings in input:

```
possible_strings <- c("foo","bar","hello",...)
```

I want to convert it into a data frame (or similar object that gets the job done) of the following format:

```
> res
        foo   bar   norf  hello
[1,  ]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
[2,  ]  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE
[3,  ]  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[...]
[200,]  FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE
```

I tried very extensively to convert it and the furthest I got was a data frame with all possible strings as column names that had the character strings in all rows, filled with NAs (I used rbind.fill in the process).

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original question, you say you'd like the result to be a data frame, but the result, `res`, you show is actually a matrix.  Therefore, my first result below is a matrix, and then I convert it to a data frame with `as.data.frame()`.

This can be done fairly easily with `sapply()` and `%in%`.  `sapply()` goes through list one element at a time and applies the function `%in%` on each element, looking for the elements of `possStr` and returning a logical result.

```
> input <- list(c("foo", "bar", "norf"), "norf", NA, c("hello", "norf"))
> possStr <- c("foo", "bar", "norf", "hello")

> d <- t(sapply(input, function(x) possStr %in% x ))
> colnames(d) <- possStr 
> d                                       ## in matrix form
#        foo   bar  norf hello
# [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

> as.data.frame(d)                        ## convert to data frame
#     foo   bar  norf hello
# 1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: You can convert the resulting matrix to a data.frame with `as.data.frame` and then set the names with `names(df) <- possStr`, if you like.

Comment: Thanks, made an edit.  But the desired result is in matrix form, so I'll leave it as a matrix and add the names

Comment: Thank you for the super fast response. I should have made one thing clearer: it is not only important for me that (for example) input[2][1] is part of possStr. It is also relevant that this results in TRUE in specifically the column of it's own name (here the "norf" column). But if here were another expression, e.g. "hello" this should result in a TRUE in the "hello" column, etc.

Comment: I tried your solution,and in fact, it does exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Awesome.  Glad I could help. By the way, keep in mind that `NA` values are gone from this result, unless you search for them in possStr.  Not sure if you need them at all.